# amazon - S3 or CloudFront - httpS custom domain

Tags: https, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm looking for some CDN where I can setup certificate for httpS

I have subdomain.site.com and I need that all files from https://subdomain.site.com hosted on amazon servers

quick look showed me that I cannot setup own httpS certificate for custom domain bucket on S3 - is this correct ?

Can Amazon CloudFront do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, appears that is not posible

Comment: Well, I think it can be done. You cannot put a custom domain https on cloud front but on S3 you can. You can have https://subdomain.site.com as your S3 - You just need to do some DNS Editing. Search google - Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can serve a CloudFront distribution over HTTPS with a custom domain now.

Amazon recently rolled out a new feature that supports custom SSL certificates at no charge using SNI (Server Name Indication): http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/

Answer (score -2):

Might be relevant. But as of today, AWS offers the ability to upload a custom SSL certificate. $600 / month. More details on their page: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Comment: A bit late to the party here but by default, this is only necessary if you need a dedicated Cloudfront IP. From AWS Cloudfront config wizard: 

Legacy clients support - $600/month prorated charge applies. *Most customers do not need this.*
CloudFront allocates dedicated IP addresses at each CloudFront edge location to serve your content over HTTPS.